# Binary AND with two false values resulting with true

Tags: c++, c, binary, bit

Very simple question, lets say I have to values in C++ and AND them

0101 & 0110 = 0100

I want the output to be the same as a boolean equal on each value IE: 1100

This needs to be a fast as possible, as this is a low level process for a performance application. I am just getting started with bit operations, so there is probably something simple for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you want a NOT(XOR(A,B))

which is in c++:

```
~(a^b);
```

Or as truth-table:

```
a | b | a^b | ~(a^b)
1 | 1 |  0  |    1
1 | 0 |  1  |    0
0 | 1 |  1  |    0
0 | 0 |  0  |    1
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for.

Comment: `~a^b` gives the same result, incidentally